# Enabling inactive fields by clicking on field

Tags: javascript, forms

Is it possible to have a group of inactive fields where if one of the fields is clicked some of the fields become mandatory and some segments of code are run? Say for example you have three fields which are shown:

```
<input type="text" id="gov1" name="gov1">

<input type="text" id="parentb" name="parentb">

<input type="checkbox" name="child" id="child">
```

All three of these fields are initially inactive; but say you click on one of the fields it now makes the rest active and mandatory, and some segment of code is run on the field "parentb" and it is attributed at readonly.

```
window.onload = function(event)
{
    var $input2 = document.getElementById('dec');
    var $input1 = document.getElementById('parentb');
    $input1.addEventListener('keyup', function()
    {
        $input2.value = $input1.value;
    });
}
```

I have done a bit of searching around but i can't seem to find anything of use for this specific situation and i'm quite new to JavaScript so any sort of help would be great. Is this at all possible using JavaScript? Or is something similar to this possible?

Comment: You want to only have one element enables at the beginning and then progressivly enable controls as more stuff is filled in?

Comment: It's all possible, but if this is going to be a big, ongoing project you may want to look at using jQuery with the Validator plug-in.
See: http://jquerytools.org/documentation/validator/

Comment: @meewoK Sorry i worded my question wrongly, say all the fields are inactive and once a checkbox is checked then the fields become active and mandatory, i have edited my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

This method you are looking is called 'chained-select' method.

jQuery framework is used for example below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get">
    <label>
    <input name="Government" type="checkbox" value="">Government</label>
    <br>
    <label>
    <input name="Parent" type="checkbox" id="parent_child_group" value="">Parent</label>
    <br>
    <label>Name of Child
    <input type="text" name="parent_child" value="" class="parent_child_group"></label>
    <br>
    <label>Other
    <input type="text" name="parent_other" value="" class="parent_child_group"></label>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $(function() {
             enable_cb();
             $("#parent_child_group").click(enable_cb);
         });

         function enable_cb() {
             if (this.checked) {
                 $("input.parent_child_group").removeAttr("disabled");
             } else {
                 $("input.parent_child_group").attr("disabled", true);
             }
         }
    });        
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Working example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/farondomenic/fg7p8/1/

Comment: Sorry i worded my question wrongly, what i was trying to say was if all the fields are inactive and once a checkbox is checked is it possible to then make some of the fields active and mandatory, i have edited my initial question

Comment: simpler than that, i want all the fields to be inactive and once a specific checkbox is checked the fields become active and some become madatory.

Comment: The examples in that link are selection lists though, i need just a checkbox once checked will activate all following fields.

Comment: almost except the other way around, selecting a checkbox enables other fields

Comment: I think I finally get what you are trying to do.  Would this be the code you were hunting for?  http://jsfiddle.net/farondomenic/fg7p8/1/?  If so, I'll revise my answer to address this.